# If statement not evaluating correctly

Tags: javascript, html

If the if statement is not there everything is good, but when it is there, then it doesn't give me numbers:

```js
let a;
no = 0;
y = document.getElementById("firstnumber");
document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = function() {
  if (firstnumber >= 0) {
    a = document.getElementById("firstnumber").value;
    console.log(a);
    document.getElementById("fdn").innerHTML = a;
    b = Number(a).toString(2);
    console.log(b);
    document.getElementById("fbn").innerHTML = b;
  }
}
```

```css
myButton {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="input">
  <label id="myText">Enter first Number</label><br>
  <input type="number" id="firstnumber"><br>
  <button type="button" id="myButton">submit</button><br>
  <label id="fdn"></label><br>
  <label id="fbn"></label>
</div>
```

In the script function there is the `if` statement and something is wrong with it. I am new to this language and don't know much about it. please help me.

Comment: `if (firstnumber >= 0) {` what is `firstnumber` ? PS `no = 0;` `y =` `b =` avoid using global variables. Also, why defining `let a` outside of scope? Also avoid the use of `.onclick` and in general `on*` handlers (unless *you*'re creating brand new elements from in-memory).

Comment: You forgot the `.value` from `firstnumber`.

Comment: Also, you're using `<label>` the wrong way. Those elements are supposed to be wrappers around (or `for`) formAction Elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`firstnumber` is `undefined` and evaluated as *false*. Therefore the code in its body will never run

```js
const el = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelector(sel); 

const elNum = el("#firstnumber");
const elBtn = el("#myButton");
const elFdn = el("#fdn");
const elFbn = el("#fbn");

elBtn.addEventListener("click", (ev) => {
  const num = Number(elNum.value);
  if (num >= 0) {
      elFdn.textContent = num;
      elFbn.textContent = num.toString(2);
  }
});
```

```css
myButton {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="input">
  <h3>Enter first Number</h3>
  <input type="number" id="firstnumber"><br>
  <button type="button" id="myButton">submit</button><br>
  <span id="fdn"></span><br>
  <span id="fbn"></span>
</div>
```

- Don't use global variables
- Don't use `on*` handlers. Use addEventListener instead
- Use `<label>` as wrappers (or `for`) FormAction Elements
- Avoid the use of `innerHTML` from a textInput to prevent malicious values ending up in your document. Use `textContent` instead